# backstage Docs Building a newer version of this documentation failed. Error

Tags: javascript

Building a newer version of this documentation failed. Error: "Failed to generate docs from /var/folders/m0/ydxv6ks52xzcdwdkn9r7qn0c0000gn/T/backstage-tDi4dI into /private/var/folders/m0/ydxv6ks52xzcdwdkn9r7qn0c0000gn/T/techdocs-tmp-oxsunu; caused by Error: This operation requires Docker. Docker does not appear to be available. Docker.ping() failed with; caused by Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/docker.sock"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz1Hm.png)

get some advice and solve problems